# JSON Tree-Child Representation in a Relational Database Model

Tags: mysql, sql, json, relational-database

I have this json tree unflattened data:

```
{
  "date": "02-02-2017",
  "records": [
    {
      "title": "Title name",
      "label": "Label name",
      "value": "Value",
      "members": [
        {
          "label": "string",
          "value": "string"
        },
        {
          "title": "Second title",
          "label": "Label",
          "value": "Value",
          "members": [
              {
                 "label": "string",
                 "value": "string"
              }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Each record can have child members, and each member, can have childs members too.

What would be a recommended representation of this json tree model, into a relational database model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing hierarchical data, closure table structure is recommended.

It is a very simple but powerful structure for storing, retrieving and deleting the data in hierarchical structure.

It will consist of just three columns - Ancestor, Descendant, Depth

You can take a look at here for more information https://coderwall.com/p/lixing/closure-tables-for-browsing-trees-in-sql

More information about other possible structures and their pitfalls are available in 'SQL Antipatterns' Book by Bill Karwin Chapter 3 'Naive trees'